# How to send info from client back to the same connection

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I need help with socket.io. I want the client to send info that the server and then the server sends it back to the same client, not all of them. Here is how the code is set up:
Client

```
var socket = io.connect();

socket.on("receive", function(data){
    console.log(data);
});

socket.emit("send", "hello");
```

Server

```
socket.on("send", function(data){
    io.sockets.emit("receive", data);
});
```

This way makes "hello" get logged to all the connections. Is there a way so that only the one that sent it receives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```
socket.on("send", function(data){
    socket.emit("receive", data);
});
```

`io.sockets.emit()` is an explict directive to send to all connected sockets whereas `socket.emit()` only sends to the one socket.

Comment: @MasterPtato - If this answers your question, then you can indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  This will indicate to the community that your question is now answered and will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure.

Comment: Ok but I don't see a green check on my phone I will do it on my computer and see